# How can I test app on my phone without usb connection with my laptop?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, adb

Is there any way I can test my apps on phone without it being connected with usb cable ? I want that because when i plug my phone in laptop it starts charging and draining laptops battery, so I would like to be able to test app on real phone without it being connected to laptop.

Comment: you can make a connection via wifi but i am sure it will also drain a little battery. Although you will be needing a usb to make wifi adb setup for the first time

Comment: what about plugging the laptop to the electric circuit.

Answer (score 0):

There is an solution  when your PC memory is low then emulator make it slow. Or computer does not support VTX

There is a github library for debugging using [WIFI only check this link.](https://github.com/pedrovgs/AndroidWiFiADB) 
The library is good for your case since only wifi is needed! Check this Introduction Quote:

> IntelliJ/AndroidStudio plugin which provides a button to connect your Android device over WiFi to install, run and debug your applications without a USB connected.

Happy Coding!